# jQuery UI Autocomplete not triggering a search when entering a hitherto searched for term

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have a jQuery UI Autocomplete control that fires an Ajax request when minLength = 3. The problem is as follows:
Say I enter "fic" as the initial search term - this is fine. The request fires and results are returned. I decide that I don't want to select any of the results and then re-enter the same search again (fic). This time no Ajax request fires!

My code is shown below:

```
// ... do request
$("#reportSearch").autocomplete({
    delay: 50,
    minLength: 3,
    source: function(q, add){
        $.ajaxSetup ({ cache: false});              
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: K_URL_REQUEST
```

So basically the "source" callback is not fired in the second scenario I described above. It appeared that the reason for this was that the autocomplete control was holding onto the previous search term and because it matched - was not triggering a search:

```
// Taken from jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.min.js
if (a.term != a.element.val()) { // *** THE MATCH IS HERE
    //console.log("a.term != a.element.val(): "+a.term+", "+a.element.val());
    a.selectedItem = null;
    a.search(null, c) // *** SEARCH IS TRIGGERED HERE
}
```

In order to get it to fire each time, I simply reset the search term to null after a search returned. This way it worked as expected.

The thing is I don't understand this behaviour. I would've thought each search should be distinct. There is no caching (or shouldn't be anyway).

So although I've fixed my problem I keep feeling that I have missed something here.

Any ideas anyone? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Whate does your [ **`search`** ](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete#event-search) event look like? As I understand it, the autocomplete should fire in your second scenario.

Comment: Note how you can enter `jav` delete it, then enter it again, and it'll still work with this demo ==> http://jsfiddle.net/KFrQm/ .

Comment: Hi Peter - I don't have a search event. It isn't necessary to kick off the search. You are right about the example. I realised this before - the only difference is that my source is an ajax request.

Comment: The jQuery Autocomplete example here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/ operates inconsistently. Put in a 'd' and it will find the result 'ColdFusion'. If you backspace delete the 'd', click away then click inside the textbox again and type 'd', sometimes it finds nothing.

Comment: Hi Peet,

Is there a version of jquery-ui-autocomplete that has this fix? Would you point me to it ? If not, please send the snippet of code I have to add to 1.8.9 jquery-ui that fixes this issue as I am also running into this problem.

thanks

Comment: No fix in jQuery that I know of. Hopefully the answer in my previous reply to you (above) makes sense

Comment: I am also having this problem - I have been looking at it for days and this post is the closest thing to a resolution I have. Unfortunately, it isn't working for me.

I have discovered that it only doesn't work when you use the same term straight away. If you search for a different term and then retry the first term, it works again.

Have you had any luck in fixing this? If you have, would you be willing to share some example source code that demonstrates the fix/workaround?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found a solution to this problem (for info, I am using jQuery UI 1.8.4)

The Autocomplete implementation in the jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.js has a method defined as _change. By commenting out the *if* statement, the control always sends the request.

```
...,
_change: function(event) {
    //if (this.previous !== this.element.val()) {
        this._trigger("change", event, { item: this.selectedItem });
    //}
},
...
```

Comment: Can confirm that this combined w/ Stefaan's answer work in 1.8.14.  Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Instead changing the jquery.ui, you can try erasing the value of the property "previous", doing something like this:
    $(this).data().autocomplete.previous = null;

Comment: i am facing the same problem in jquerymobile autocomplete here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/q/18798630/2307391

Comment: gezequiel's answer worked for me, only in my case it was: $(this).data().autocomplete.term = null;

Comment: on jQuery ui 1.10.2 `$(this).data().uiAutocomplete.term = null;` worked for me

Comment: Using the API instead of modifying the source code is the better way to go!

Answer (score 6):

i've managed to solve this problem by comment out this if-statement in the source of the jquery ui autocomplete.

```
// keypress is triggered before the input value is changed
clearTimeout( self.searching );
self.searching = setTimeout(function() {
    // only search if the value has changed
    //if ( self.term != self.element.val() ) {
        self.selectedItem = null;
        self.search( null, event );
    //}
}, self.options.delay );
```

Answer (score 1):

Since JQuery UI 1.8+ you can use the widget factory to extend the default behavior of all your autocomplete widgets.
Simply include a javascript file with this content after jqueryUI

```
// Extend jquery UI autocomplete
$.widget( "ui.autocomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _close: function( event ) {
        var ret = this._super();

        // Resets previously used search term
        this.term = null;

        return ret;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Great tips here - this is something I've been struggling with for a while.

For me, the only solution that consistently works is a combination of Duncan's and Stefaan's answers above.